# Will I cause any damage with a mismatched wheel set?

Tags: wheels

This might seem like a silly question but I would just rather confirm. I recently bought a new wheel set to replace my front wheel, as I was in an accident. However, I was unaware that Id need special tools to remove the cassette from the rear wheel frame.

I'd still like to be able to use my bike in the mean time, whilst I wait for the tools to be delivered. Would that be okay to use a mismatched wheel set for ~2 days (50 miles) until the tools arrive?

For clarification, the spec is the same, just weight and branding is different.

Comment: The wheels could even be different sizes.  So long as the brakes work and nothing drags, there's no reason the two wheels must match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run different wheels in the front and back (different brands are fine). Heck, some bicycles have different sizes in the front and back (and are sold that way; 96ers and 69ers are examples)!

The only thing you need to make sure is that the wheel fits in the frame and the brakes work.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention what is mismatched about the wheel set, but if it fits the bike it is hard to imagine what kind of problems you might have. The worst that I can think of is at you'd alter the geometry a bit – for example if you have a 27" rear wheel and a 700c front you'd be making the frame angles (relative to the ground) a bit steeper.

I've been riding a bike with that configuration (27" rear, 700c front, and similar sized tires) for about six months will no ill effects that I've noticed.